# Can't access docker from LAN

Tags: docker, networking

I am running docker on my physic fedora machine.I started a prometheus container with host network, I think I should be able to access prometheus web pages from other host in the same local network, but failed.

My machina's ip is 172.31.209.112, the host I want to access prometheus is 172.31.1.195 on which I can ping 172.31.209.112. I can also confirm firewall is not running on both sides.

To access the LAN network I need to install a security software, which only has windows version, so I installed a windows vm with network set to NAT to cheat the security software, but I don't think this have something to do with my docker accessing problem.

I can access prometheus with localhost:9090 or 172.31.209.112:9090 locally, but just can't access it from any hosts in LAN, please help.

here is my docker container config:

```
{
        "Id": "88b4c38e6a659754e861976b6b8b11d1dff495db1ef3d572169065a2e0acf4f6",
        "Created": "2019-07-03T10:06:59.61293669Z",
        "Path": "/bin/prometheus",
        "Args": [
            "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml",
            "--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus",
            "--web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries",
            "--web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 5687,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2019-07-03T10:06:59.836329996Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:5d62a6125e7e0121151c24f6ec132bfae02cc37a2b57a666fd0569bed66d498f",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/88b4c38e6a659754e861976b6b8b11d1dff495db1ef3d572169065a2e0acf4f6/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/88b4c38e6a659754e861976b6b8b11d1dff495db1ef3d572169065a2e0acf4f6/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/88b4c38e6a659754e861976b6b8b11d1dff495db1ef3d572169065a2e0acf4f6/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/88b4c38e6a659754e861976b6b8b11d1dff495db1ef3d572169065a2e0acf4f6/88b4c38e6a659754e861976b6b8b11d1dff495db1ef3d572169065a2e0acf4f6-json.log",
        "Name": "/elastic_kapitsa",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/home/ggfan/4-tmp/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "host",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "shareable",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d1e89e203e0a0791e370911f07f112a56603be51af65c29fc679b0c78350d4bf-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/64e3d0a748213274b8210bde9f849e09e40aa59214cec724f0ef3167ed0d8030/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/197e352b2464399aef2da8a75f31cb78179c3ad7b7e03b517176694fca19e7bc/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2a601b39acac1f8054c28af2d68004611ee17417c82d9c12842fc1b4725d18f5/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3590491c1df9eb9d1f4272abad88a6ad44f7f7e169129b8a6bdbba8a02fca09f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0b1a049f0c204896187f0a3050a43eeb7d226fd0bfa810149f689039215d0068/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8c3523f1a5d77616be86ca76850c2cb682728c9d349032c0809781e3a9f24839/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b95196ec6ef2ed89345e6ecda9c476a30266a14097ca3931169159e01d5610b8/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/56f16ca07e36898774523cb9d17bb5fc4d9c6526579bc3d764d257c41970e5bb/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/749405b668264446ef9ec29a24089b5ce7dc7b9363033afab5dfa765ad1980e6/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d1e89e203e0a0791e370911f07f112a56603be51af65c29fc679b0c78350d4bf/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d1e89e203e0a0791e370911f07f112a56603be51af65c29fc679b0c78350d4bf/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d1e89e203e0a0791e370911f07f112a56603be51af65c29fc679b0c78350d4bf/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/home/ggfan/4-tmp/prometheus/prometheus.yml",
                "Destination": "/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "833a1e3a523e0e3061f937ef9868413342ba9277c079b8f3bab5d363a884aa44",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/833a1e3a523e0e3061f937ef9868413342ba9277c079b8f3bab5d363a884aa44/_data",
                "Destination": "/prometheus",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "localhost.localdomain",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "nobody",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "9090/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml",
                "--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus",
                "--web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries",
                "--web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "prom/prometheus",
            "Volumes": {
                "/prometheus": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/prometheus",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/bin/prometheus"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "maintainer": "The Prometheus Authors <prometheus-developers@googlegroups.com>"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "5029bdc13e1f15aebb36e2d5a84c6d34f2d078360705a577946f92268b59a37e",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/default",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "host": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "d58749e2d0012b4e59f12097a590b4814258fad4a99252a21df1c2863f5ca03b",
                    "EndpointID": "7238756953fc7ea91d9364c17a7730658f2057b583508bd1ea8ebcbffd1f6ab5",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

my network:

```
docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:10ff:fe57:b91  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:10:57:0b:91  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 33469  bytes 5113347 (4.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 40202  bytes 4779129 (4.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s31f6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.31.209.112  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.31.209.255
        inet6 fe80::7ab9:b4e3:e089:36e3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 18:66:da:45:1f:63  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2448716  bytes 386681103 (368.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 761559  bytes 192020136 (183.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xf7180000-f71a0000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 256361  bytes 332219233 (316.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 256361  bytes 332219233 (316.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth19c1c5e: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::e80f:ccff:fefb:f2a1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ea:0f:cc:fb:f2:a1  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 83  bytes 285072 (278.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5896  bytes 1195103 (1.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth4586d02: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::24c6:88ff:fe1b:41ea  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 26:c6:88:1b:41:ea  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 39  bytes 2718 (2.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6957  bytes 1410747 (1.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:2c:67:b9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0-nic: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:2c:67:b9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vmnet1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.131.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        inet6 fe80::eb22:59d6:882e:9200  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14178  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 9  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6603  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and my routes:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s31f6
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     101    0        0 vmnet1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.31.0.0      _gateway        255.255.0.0     UG    100    0        0 enp0s31f6
172.31.209.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s31f6
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
224.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         240.0.0.0       U     101    0        0 vmnet1
```

Comment: Do you have a firewall running on your Prometheus target machine ? Is the port 9090 opened to other IPs than localhost ? And while we're at it: do you have a firewall running on the source machine that would prevent connecting to port 9090 on the outside ? Can you ping your prometheus host from your source machine ?

Comment: I can ping prometheus host from 172.31.1.195, firewall on both side are disabled.